# How can i make my Hit counter to count daily, weekly and monthy?

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have this simple HIT COUNTER, but i want to make it display total Hits based on daily, weekly, monthly and yearly.

Example:
Today - 24 counts
Yesterday - 8 counts
Last month - 45 counts
April - xx counts
March - xx counts
February - xx counts

Just something simple but similar to the above example.
I'll appreciate if someone can help me modify my code to achieve this goal.

Bellow is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE `counter` ( `counter` INT( 20 ) NOT NULL );
INSERT INTO counter VALUES (0);

<?php
//Adds one to the counter
mysql_query("UPDATE counter SET counter = counter + 1");
//Retrieves the current count
$count = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT counter FROM counter"));
//Displays the count on your site
print "$count[0]";
?>
```

Comment: MySQL's [DATEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) and [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) are your friends on this one. Of course, use `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: I can't believe there are still people out there using `mysql_*`.. It's been deprecated for 4+ years now? And it doesn't even work in PHP7+ anymore. How many more hints do you need before you realise you should no longer use it and use MySQLi or PDO instead?

Comment: Well if you want to do calculations by date it would probably be helpful to actually store a date.

Comment: Cant be done without tracking individual hits with dates, you can have daily, weekly, monthly and yearly cron jobs to build reports and truncate/consolidate rows, or just deal with many rows.

Comment: you realize that you'll be updating your entire database, unless that's what you want. It doesn't make much sense having a database with just one column.

Answer (score 1):

To get you started:

```
CREATE TABLE `counter` (
  `datestamp` DATE NOT NULL,
  `counter` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`datestamp`)
);
```

And then replace that `UPDATE` with:

```
INSERT INTO `counter` (`datestamp`, `counter`) VALUES ( DATE(NOW()), 1 )
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `counter` = `counter` + 1;
```

Ref:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

Now you've got some date information to aggregate on, and you're not storing a row per hit, which would be fairly wasteful.